# Show the save as dialog when exporting in csv from Access

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm using this simple code module to export a table in a csv file:

```
Function ExportQuery()
 DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "[Name of the Specific]", "[Name of the query]","[Name of file].csv"
End Function
```

But this exports the file in Documents Folder.

How can I do to make that when this module runs, it open the save as dialog and let me choose the folder in which save the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the code

```
Dim getFolder As Object
Dim sLoc as string

Set getFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With getFolder
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = True Then
        sLoc = getFolder.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End If
end with
```

Then you can add your code like

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "[Name of the Specific]", "[Name of the query]", sLoc & [Name of file].csv
```

Comment: Set a reference to the MS Office Type Library if you want to use that named constant (*msoFileDialogFolderPicker*).  Alternatively, you could substitute the constant's value (4) and avoid the need to set a reference.

Comment: Oh year sorry I got to mention that. However VBA might notice it needs it and ask to add automattically.

Comment: If you can get Access to do that, please tell me how.  Thanks.

Comment: I cannot replicate it now. However when I first added it into my code a dialog popped up saying something like this may need an reference to work. Do you want to add it. But I cannot get it to come up again. But might be best to just use the value 4 instead of the full name